# Why is cycle taking only saved texture to render when EEVE takes the current texture? Possible to change?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I was experimenting with multiple uvmaps/textures painting... today, and I noticed something very disturbing (I lost like 1h on that thinking that my nodes where not configured properly...)

Basically, I noticed that when I'm in the "display render preview" mode, and when I put on a mesh an UV mapped texture, the version of the used UV map texture is different for EEVE and cycle rendering:

- for EEVE (in both "render preview" et "material preview mode"), it takes the version that is being edited right now
- for cycle (cycle is used only in the "render preview" mode anyway), it takes the version that is saved on disk

Consider for example this displayed with EEVE (what an artist!):
[image]

and the same displaed by cycle:
[image]

As you can see, the green, newly added part is not displayed. But if I save my picture, it is updated. And here is the nodes I'm using:

[image]

Is there any reason why cycle forces me to save my texture before rendering? Can I setup cycle to always display the non-saved version of the picture? It could be cool to get an instantaneous feedback instead of saving at every stroke.

PS: unrelated, but is the Mapping/texture node required when using UV maps? I see it's often added but I'm not sure to see why it's useful, the image displays fine without any input vector.

Comment: By default, Image Texture node uses the "raw" UV Coords ; but if you want to do something to those coordinates (like, using a Mapping node, or a Vector Math), you'll need to add a Texture Coordinate ; because those nodes use something else as a default (I guess, a unit vector or a null vector).

Comment: @thibsert ok thanks! Any idea about "auto saving" texture in cycle?